# Oracle Change Notification Listener in a web application

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, listener, wildfly

I have implemented Oracle Change Notification to listen to an oracle database and push changes to a Java listener.

However, I have no idea tom implement this in a web app running on an application server.

Here is what I have tried

**First**, I have created a ServletContextListener to register a query change notification on initialization.

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener{


   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // unregister
   }

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //register
   }
}
```

**Then** I have the database change listener here to do something with the code when a database change event occurs.

```
public class MyListener implements DatabaseChangeListener {

   @Override
   public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println("Change is found");
      //do something
   }
}
```

And then I have added the listener to the **web.xml**

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
         mypackage.ContextListener
    </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Now this has worked the first time. However, for some reason it stopped and I'm not getting notification anymore.

I have no idea if this is even the right approach.

Environment:
Wildfly (10.x)
Oracle DB